# Convert Branch and Bound loop to use Java Stream API

Tags: java, algorithm, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a simple Branch and Bound algorithm that works on a variant of the Traveling Salesman problem and I thought it would be fun to try and convert it to use the Java 8 Stream API. I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to do it without relying on side effects, however.

**Initial Code**

```
int bound = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
List<Location> bestPath = null;

while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Node curr = queue.poll();
    //bound exceeds best, bail
    if (curr.getBound() >= bound) { 
        return bestPath;
    }
    //have a complete path, save it
    if(curr.getPath().size() == locations.size()) {
        bestPath = curr.getPath();
        bound = curr.getBound();
        continue;
    }
    //incomplete path - add all possible next steps
    Set<Location> unvisited = new HashSet<>(locations);
    unvisited.removeAll(curr.getPath());
    for (Location l : unvisited) {
        List<Location> newPath = new ArrayList<>(curr.getPath());
        newPath.add(l);
        Node newNode = new Node(newPath, getBoundForPath(newPath));
        if (newNode.getBound() <= bound){
            queue.add(newNode);
        }
    }
}
```

I took a first shot at converting it to the Stream API and came up with the following:

**Java 8 Version**

```
Consumer<Node> nodeConsumer = node -> {
    if(node.getPath().size() == locations.size() ) {
        bestPath = node.getPath();
        bound = node.getBound();
    } else {
        locations.stream()
            .filter(l -> !node.getPath().contains(l))
            .map(l -> {
                List<Location> newPath = new ArrayList<>(node.getPath());
                newPath.add(s);
                return new Node(newPath, getBoundForPath(newPath));
            })
            .filter(newNode -> newNode.getBound() <= bound)
            .forEach(queue::add);
    }
};

Stream.generate(() -> queue.poll())
    .peek(nodeConsumer)
    .filter(s -> s.getBound() > bound)
    .findFirst();

return bestPath;
```

The main problem is that the nodeConsumer has to reference bestPath and bound, which are not final variables. I could make them final AtomicReference variables to work around this, but I feel like this sort of violates the spirit of the stream API. Can anyone help me distill the initial algorithm into a more idiomatic implementation?

Comment: I don't think you can get something much better without abusing the API. Stream API is not for such algorithms. Nevertheless the problem is interesting.

Comment: @TagirValeev Thanks for the response. Still getting used to the new options available to me and have a hard time identifying whether a thing is difficult because I'm doing it wrong, or difficult because it's not an ideal usage.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if using `reduce` is the way to go about this, as it allows you to track values without the need for external variables.

Something like the following (I've had to guess at a few of the details of your above code, but hopefully I'm on the right track).

```
    final BiFunction<Entry<Integer, List<Location>>, Node, Entry<Integer, List<Location>>> accumulator
        = (identity, node) -> {
            if (node.getPath().size() == locations.size() ) {
                return new SimpleEntry<>(node.getBound(), node.getPath());
            } else {
                locations.stream()
                    .filter(l -> !node.getPath().contains(l))
                    .map(l -> {
                        List<Location> newPath = new ArrayList<>(node.getPath());
                        newPath.add(l);
                        return new Node(newPath, getBoundForPath(newPath));
                    })
                    .filter(newNode -> newNode.getBound() <= identity.getKey())
                    .forEach(queue::add);
                return identity;
            }
        };

    final BinaryOperator<Entry<Integer, List<Location>>> combiner
        = (left, right) -> left.getKey() < right.getKey() ? left : right;

    final Entry<Integer, List<Location>> identity
        = new SimpleEntry<>(Integer.MAX_VALUE, null);

    final List<Location> bestValue = Stream.generate(queue::poll)
        .reduce(identity, accumulator, combiner)
        .getValue();
```

Alternatively, you could look at using `Seq` in [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) (a sequential extension to Streams), and use `foldLeft` instead.